# wxPython class refactoring

Tags: refactoring, wxpython

I would like to refactor the class in wxPython so it can be used as a tab in wx.Notebook, now is opening in new window. I never done something like that, 
and I am new to WXPython. Thank you for any advice!

```
class StlPlater(Plater):

load_wildcard = _("STL files (*.stl;*.STL)|*.stl;*.STL|OpenSCAD files (*.scad)|*.scad")
save_wildcard = _("STL files (*.stl;*.STL)|*.stl;*.STL")

def __init__(self, filenames = [], size = (800, 580), callback = None,
             parent = None, build_dimensions = None, circular_platform = False,
             simarrange_path = None, antialias_samples = 0):
    super(StlPlater, self).__init__(filenames, size, callback, parent, build_dimensions)
    self.cutting = False
    self.cutting_axis = None
    self.cutting_dist = None
    if glview:
        viewer = stlview.StlViewPanel(self, (580, 580),
                                      build_dimensions = self.build_dimensions,
                                      circular = circular_platform,
                                      antialias_samples = antialias_samples)
        # Cutting tool
        nrows = self.menusizer.GetRows()
        self.menusizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self.menupanel, -1, _("Cut along:")),
                           pos = (nrows, 0), span = (1, 1), flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        cutconfirmbutton = wx.Button(self.menupanel, label = _("Confirm cut"))
        cutconfirmbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.cut_confirm)
        cutconfirmbutton.Disable()
        self.cutconfirmbutton = cutconfirmbutton
        self.menusizer.Add(cutconfirmbutton, pos = (nrows, 1), span = (1, 1), flag = wx.EXPAND)
        cutpanel = wx.Panel(self.menupanel, -1)
        cutsizer = self.cutsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        cutpanel.SetSizer(cutsizer)
        cutxplusbutton = wx.ToggleButton(cutpanel, label = _(">X"), style = wx.BU_EXACTFIT)
        cutxplusbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, lambda event: self.start_cutting_tool(event, "x", 1))
        cutsizer.Add(cutxplusbutton, 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)
        cutzplusbutton = wx.ToggleButton(cutpanel, label = _(">Y"), style = wx.BU_EXACTFIT)
        cutzplusbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, lambda event: self.start_cutting_tool(event, "y", 1))
        cutsizer.Add(cutzplusbutton, 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)
        cutzplusbutton = wx.ToggleButton(cutpanel, label = _(">Z"), style = wx.BU_EXACTFIT)
        cutzplusbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, lambda event: self.start_cutting_tool(event, "z", 1))
        cutsizer.Add(cutzplusbutton, 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)
        cutxminusbutton = wx.ToggleButton(cutpanel, label = _("<X"), style = wx.BU_EXACTFIT)
        cutxminusbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, lambda event: self.start_cutting_tool(event, "x", -1))
        cutsizer.Add(cutxminusbutton, 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)
        cutzminusbutton = wx.ToggleButton(cutpanel, label = _("<Y"), style = wx.BU_EXACTFIT)
        cutzminusbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, lambda event: self.start_cutting_tool(event, "y", -1))
        cutsizer.Add(cutzminusbutton, 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)
        cutzminusbutton = wx.ToggleButton(cutpanel, label = _("<Z"), style = wx.BU_EXACTFIT)
        cutzminusbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, lambda event: self.start_cutting_tool(event, "z", -1))
        cutsizer.Add(cutzminusbutton, 1, flag = wx.EXPAND)
        self.menusizer.Add(cutpanel, pos = (nrows + 1, 0), span = (1, 2), flag = wx.EXPAND)
    else:
        viewer = showstl(self, (580, 580), (0, 0))
    self.simarrange_path = simarrange_path if simarrange_path else "./simarrange/sa"
    self.set_viewer(viewer)

def start_cutting_tool(self, event, axis, direction):
    toggle = event.GetEventObject()
    if toggle.GetValue():
        # Disable the other toggles
        for child in self.cutsizer.GetChildren():
            child = child.GetWindow()
            if child != toggle:
                child.SetValue(False)
        self.cutting = True
        self.cutting_axis = axis
        self.cutting_dist = None
        self.cutting_direction = direction
    else:
        self.cutting = False
        self.cutting_axis = None
        self.cutting_dist = None
        self.cutting_direction = None

def cut_confirm(self, event):
    name = self.l.GetSelection()
    name = self.l.GetString(name)
    model = self.models[name]
    transformation = transformation_matrix(model)
    transformed = model.transform(transformation)
    print _("Cutting %s alongside %s axis") % (name, self.cutting_axis)
    axes = ["x", "y", "z"]
    cut = transformed.cut(axes.index(self.cutting_axis),
                          self.cutting_direction,
                          self.cutting_dist)
    cut.offsets = [0, 0, 0]
    cut.rot = 0
    cut.scale = model.scale
    cut.filename = model.filename
    cut.centeroffset = [0, 0, 0]
    self.s.prepare_model(cut, 2)
    self.models[name] = cut
    self.cutconfirmbutton.Disable()
    self.cutting = False
    self.cutting_axis = None
    self.cutting_dist = None
    self.cutting_direction = None
    for child in self.cutsizer.GetChildren():
        child = child.GetWindow()
        child.SetValue(False)
```